# Prevent Firefox from going to first search result

Tags: firefox, search

When I type some terms in the address bar (not the search box!) and hit enter, Firefox searches for those terms on Google, and, depending on some logic either takes me to the search results page or takes me to the first search result. Now, I want it to always take me to the search results page (like Chrome does). Is this possible?

And, yes, I am aware that the search box does exactly that, but I'm using it for some other search engine. So, another solution would be to add additional search box, that can also work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type `about:config` in the address bar, search for `keyword.URL` (case-insensitive), right-click and click `Reset`. Alternatively, for the last step, double-click and set to something like `http://www.google.com/search?q=` (the search parameter is appended to the URL provided). Or, set it to nothing (empty string) to get the same effect as setting `keyword.enabled` to false.

Source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/keyword.URL

Alternatively, set `keyword.enabled` to false to completely disable searching from the address bar. (Don't think this is what you want; really here for the sake of comprehensiveness)

Source: http://kb.mozillazine.org/keyword.enabled

Comment: Actually, the keyword.URL was already reset, but I just removed the "I'm feeling lucky" part from it (gfns=1), and it always takes me to results page. Thanks!